# найди 2 одинаковых слова в одной строке и выбери только цифры

Tags: sed, grep

У меня есть html файл с номерами. Мне нужно выбрать только цифры. Как получить только номера в виде

```
260573
261374
259249 

<p class="list-item">
    <span style="margin-left: 20px" class="padding"></span>
    <span class="icon left drop-down-icon" onclick="toggle(this, '2A4FFFC5-DA6B-4B3B-A16D-5083449D1E13')"></span>
    testIT: C260573, testIT: C261374, testIT: C259249 (2m30s)
    <span class="icon paperclip-icon" style="display: none"></span>
  </p>
```

Я сделал

sed -n -e 's/^.*testIT: C//p' | sed -r 's/ .+//'

но я получаю только последний 259249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

здесь можно и одним `awk` обойтись указав необходимые разделители:

```
awk -F'testIT: C|, | \\(' '/testIT:/{print $2"\n"$4"\n"$6}' |awk 'NF!=0'
```

Comment: А если у меня будет в отчете testIT: C260573 (2m30s)  Или testIT: C260573, testIT: C261374 (2m30s) ?

Comment: @Yaroslav, тогда уточняйте условие задачи если у вас там может быть разное количество нужных значений в строке, в данном случае код обрабатывает до трёх значений, если их меньше то просто выведет на том месте пустую строку что в принципе можно легко убрать добавив в конце `...| awk 'NF!=0'` (добавил в ответе)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
grep -oP '(?<=testIT: C)[0-9]{6}'
```

Проверяем позитивным просмотром назад, что перед 6 цифрами есть текст "testIT: C"
Параметры программы:
`-o` - вывод только попавших под захват данных
`-P` - включение расширенной библиотеки регулярных выражений

Регулярное выражение:
`(?<=...)` - позитивный просмотр назад, группа проверяет данные, но не выполняет захват
`[0-9]` - цифры в диапазоне от 0 до 9
`{6}` - квантификатор, 6 совпадений

Если количество цифр не известно, то можно установить квантификатор `+` - одно и более совпадений, так же можно регулировать минимальное/максимальное количество совпадений `{3,}` - что означает 3 и более символа предыдущего шаблона
или `{1,6}` от одного до шести символов соответствующих предыдущему шаблону.